# How to get "two column" paragraph headers?

Tags: lists, description

I am a LaTeX newbie and would appreciate some guidance.

How can I achieve paragraph headers like this?
[image]

The associated paragraph does not go down all the way to the left, but rather it is as if the headers and the paragraphs are in separate columns.

Comment: Just use a table or search this site for `description` with aligned indent. And welcome to our site!

Comment: To allow for multiple line labels, add `style=multiline` to the options for `description` in the answer linked by henrique.

Answer (score 1):

As LaRiFaRi suggested, try using a table for this purpose instead of a paragraph.

The following code should provide you with the desired outcome:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6} % for the extra space between the rows

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{10cm}}

\textbf{Responsibilities \& Goals} & Head of Recruitment; 50+ employees/year to 6 different business divisions. Sales, ongoing IT projects, development of the IT business unit.\\
\textbf{Tasks Performed} & Established a new recruitment strategy. Managed and supervised several projects. Trained and re-created the IT business unit.\\
\textbf{Achievements} & Reversed trend of decreased amount of IT-recruits. Work by the new IT-team accounted for more than 50 \% of the company's revenue. Each team member generated 3 times the revenue of other employees.\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Of course you can change the width of the tables by defining different parameters for `p{3cm}` and `p{10cm}`.

[image]

Based on the suggestions by LaRiFari and Alan, I adjusted the code to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{longtable}[H]{p{0.25\textwidth} p{0.7\textwidth}}

\bfseries Responsibilities \& Goals & Head of Recruitment; 50+ employees/year to 6 different business divisions. Sales, ongoing IT projects, development of the IT business unit.\\[0.2cm]
\bfseries Tasks Performed & Established a new recruitment strategy. Managed and supervised several projects. Trained and re-created the IT business unit.\\[0.2cm]
\bfseries Achievements & Reversed trend of decreased amount of IT-recruits. Work by the new IT-team accounted for more than 50 \% of the company's revenue. Each team member generated 3 times the revenue of other employees.\\[0.2cm]

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This provides you with an output closely aligned to your textwidth and without messing up the other tables in your document. The longtable allows page breaking of the table over multiple pages.

[image]

Comment: +1 for all your effort. Please do not use a float here, as it is most certainly not desired. Put the `\renewcommand` locally, as it could redefine all other tables of the OP. Have a look on `\SI{50}{\percent}` of `siunitx` and on `{>{\bfseries}p{3cm}p{10cm}}` from `array`. I guess, the op would like to get this text aligned to the page margins on both sides.

Comment: Also, for this kind of use, a `longtable`   would probably be better to use since it will break across pages if needed. (Obviously for a one-page resume, not necessary, but for something like a CV yes.)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to align the table columns exactly to the textwidth would be greatly appreciated. I will edit my post accordingly.